# My Visual Studio Code won't run my code properly

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I can't properly run/debug my code in VS Code using the C language. I've installed C/C++ package on VSC, Mingw & applied the path for Mingw. All my files are running .c format as well.

Only the last part of my code keeps crashing in VSC, when I run this same code on website compilers, it works!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1;
    int num2;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("Answer: %d ", num1 + num2);
    return 0;
}
```

That last `printf` is where VSC just shuts down the output window, so I never get to see the end result of my code. Anyone have any solutions to fix this? It'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add a `getc()` before return or set it up to use its own builtin terminal, that will not disappear when the program ends.

Comment: it doesn't crash. It just closes the terminal window when the program terminates. Shows us tasks.json

Comment: @Eraklon: a single `getc()` will just read the ending newline left in the input stream by `scanf()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your console program from Visual Studio, it opens a terminal window, runs the program and the terminal window closes automatically when the program exits. This is a classic problem with the Microsoft Windows platform that they do not seem to care about despite millions of newbie programmers like you experiencing the same problem.

If you open the terminal window yourself, by running the `CMD` command from the start menu, you will be able to run your program manually after changing the current directory to that of the program binary.

To prevent the terminal window from closing immediately when running directly from Visual Studio, you should add 2 `getchar();` statements before returning from `main()` to wait for user input and get a chance to see the output. Just reading a single byte with `getchar()` will not suffice because it will just read the pending newline entered by the user in response to the second prompt.

Also note that it is preferable to output a trailing newline to ensure the output is properly flushed on some legacy systems:

```
printf("Answer: %d\n", num1 + num2);
```

Here is a modified program you can test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("Answer: %d\n", num1 + num2);

    getchar(); // read the pending newline
    getchar(); // read at least another byte from the user.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run you program from the console:

1. In the search box type `cmd`
2. `cd \path_to_your_executable`
3. run your program.